# Rotating a 3 dimensional array

Tags: go, multidimensional-array

I'm using them to make a functional rubix cube where I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I would go about rotating the cube to see other sides.

I've created an array with 27 cubes with 6 sides each that have a color written on the outer facing sides of them, I was wondering if there was an easier way for me to rotate all the values in the cube rather than going to all the faces of each cube and changing them manually to the one they need to be.

Here is the code for creating the cube, let me know if you can think of a way to go about doing this, thanks in advance.

```
func constructcube() (newcube [3][3][3][6]string) {
    for d := 0; d < 3; d++ {
        for h := 0; h < 3; h++ {
            for w := 0; w < 3; w++ {
                for f := 0; f < 6; f++ {
                    newcube[d][h][w][f] = " "
                    switch f {
                    case 0:
                        if d == 2 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "m"
                        }
                    case 1:
                        if w == 0 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "y"
                        }
                    case 2:
                        if d == 0 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "r"
                        }
                    case 3:
                        if w == 2 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "c"
                        }
                    case 4:
                        if h == 0 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "b"
                        }
                    case 5:
                        if h == 2 {
                            newcube[d][h][w][f] = "g"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newcube
}
```

Comment: While a Rubik-Cube is rendered in three-dimensional space - I would not represent it as such in code. If you are looking to solve patterns and switch between cube states, flatten the model - say 6 independent sides with a 3x3 array. The turn operations e.g. `FLUB` should lead to natural transformation functions. The reverse operations e.g. `'F` can be coded logically as 3 runs of the `F` operation.

Answer (score 0):

To start representing rotations we have to identify an efficient way which goes much simpler than what we see in the screen. when computing graphics, the machine not always render everything a scene has but only what is in the view port. your problem as many others has to abstract away from what it is in reality. In Go terms we gonna flatten the cube and use slices.

#### [Slices to the rescue](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

With slices we can reference blocks/parts of an array and play around with them, move, cut, intersect etc.
I will use a cube of 3x3 where numbers "are colours" and if you can visualize a dotted line by every group of 3 numbers, you could also imagine folding this into a real cube.

```
// cube represents a 3x3 3d cube
// the view is 2d tho
var cube = [][]int{
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {2,2,2},
    {2,2,2},
    {2,2,2},
    {3,3,3},
    {3,3,3},
    {3,3,3},
    {4,4,4},
    {4,4,4},
    {4,4,4},
}
```

playing with the cube means moving a column or a row entirely, but what is displayed in the view port is just the front of the cube — we will take care of that in a later step.
moving one row to the left, moves every element of that row, with slices we do

```
// moves the cube row to the left
func left(r int)  {
    f := cube[r][:3] // slice the first 3 elements of the row
    cube[r] = append(cube[r][3:], f...) // append those to the back, while removing the first 3 and creating a new slice
}
```

this pattern repeats for all interactions with the cube

```
// moves the cube row to the right
func right(r int)  {
    b := cube[r][len(cube[r])-3:]
    cube[r] = append(b, cube[r][:len(cube[r])-3]...)
}
```

to move right we take the elements from the back and prepend them...
to forward(up) and backward(down) movements we will retrieve the whole column and apply the same approach

```
// forward moves the cube's (c)column forward(up)
func forward(c int)  {
    r := flatten(c) // retrieve the whole column
    a := r[:3]
    r = append(r[3:], a...)
    move(c, r) // apply the new position
}

// flatten percolates the (c)olumn position and return a flatten slice of its entire
func flatten(c int) []int {
    var r []int
    for _, v := range cube {
        r = append(r, v[c])
    }

    return r
}

// move moves the cube (c)olumn to (p)osition
func move(c int, p []int)  {
    for i := range cube {
        cube[i][c] = p[i]
    }
}
```

all that is cool and without nested iterations, but none of this work. the reason is that we are changing the position of the elements and in order to achieve what we want we have to either copy, and recreate(relocation) or make a reference.

I used the examples without the pointers in an attempt to make them a bit cleaner;
bellow you will find the full functioning example.

keep in mind that might exist many different approaches for such problem, probably a proper much efficient algorithm. here is just an example of how to leverage go slices functionality to simplify array manipulation and avoid scenarios such nested iterations.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// cube represents a 3x3 3d cube
// the view is 2d tho
var cube = []*[]int{
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4},
    {2,2,2},
    {2,2,2},
    {2,2,2},
    {3,3,3},
    {3,3,3},
    {3,3,3},
    {4,4,4},
    {4,4,4},
    {4,4,4},
}

func main() {
    display()
    forward(1)
    left(1)
    display()
    backward(1)
    display()
}

// moves the cube's (c)olumn backwards(down)
func backward(c int)  {
    r := flatten(c)
    a := r[len(r)-3:]
    r = append(a, r[:len(r)-3]...)
    move(c, r)
}

// forward moves the cube's (c)column forward(up)
func forward(c int)  {
    r := flatten(c)
    a := r[:3]
    r = append(r[3:], a...)
    move(c, r)
}

// moves the cube row to the left
func left(r int)  {
    f := (*cube[r])[:3]
    *cube[r] = append((*cube[r])[3:], f...)
}

// moves the cube row to the right
func right(r int)  {
    b := (*cube[r])[len(*cube[r])-3:]
    *cube[r] = append(b, (*cube[r])[:len(*cube[r])-3]...)
}

// display the front view of the cube
func display()  {
    for y := 0; y < 3; y++ {
        fmt.Printf("[")
        for x := 0; x < 3; x++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d", (*cube[y])[x])
            if x < 2 {
                fmt.Printf("\t")
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("]")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

// flatten percolates the (c)olumn position and return a flatten slice of its entire
func flatten(c int) []int {
    var r []int
    for _, v := range cube {
        r = append(r, (*v)[c])
    }

    return r
}

// move moves the cube (c)olumn to (p)osition
func move(c int, p []int)  {
    for i := range cube {
        (*cube[i])[c] = p[i]
    }
}
```

***disclaimer***

the script relies on the existence of `cube` variable with a face of 3x3 square. no index checks are being made, warning `out of bounds` panics.

https://play.golang.com/p/Z7azOi0omP3

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out how to do this with something called "rotation matrices" where you take the coordinate of each point on the graph and change it from {i, j, k} to {i, k, -j} and it rotates the 3-dimensional object. I had to play around with some test input and line it up right with the actual output, and since the values couldn't be negative in this case I figured out you just subtract them from the upper limit of the cube side, that being 2.